Can we use the operator $\frac {d}{dx}$ to solve homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients?
Considering the ODE with real coefficient:$$\qquad  y^{(n)}+a_1y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_{n-1}y^{\prime}+a_ny=0,a_k\in \mathbb R,k=1..n-1$$Let $\frac{d}{dx}=D$ and $$p(D)=D^n+a_1D^{n-1}+..+a_{n-1}D+a_n=(D-\lambda_1)^{n_1}...(D-\lambda_s)^{n_s}$$where $\lambda_j$ is the root of the polynomial with multiplicity $n_j$.
We can write the equation above as:$$p(D)y=0$$

Question:Can we use the operator $D$ to solve the equation?More
precisely,I know the solution to this equation would
be:$$\begin{cases}&e^{\lambda_1x}, xe^{\lambda_1x}, \cdots,
 x^{n_1-1}e^{\lambda_1x}\\&\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\\&e^{\lambda_sx},
 xe^{\lambda_sx}, \cdots , x^{n_s-1}e^{\lambda_sx}\end{cases}$$We can
deduce these solutions by checking the functions above are solutions
and are linearly independent. But how can we use the operator $D$ to
get the same answer?

My attempt:From Operator Calculus we know that:$$D-\lambda_j=e^{\lambda_jx}D^{}e^{-\lambda_jx}$$Now we can write the original equation as:$$\prod_{j=1}^s(e^{\lambda_jx}D^{}e^{-\lambda_jx})^{n_j}y=\prod_{j=1}^s\big(e^{\lambda_jx}(\frac{d}{dx})^{n_j}e^{-\lambda_jx}\big)y=0$$But things start to become messy:$$(\frac{d}{dx})^{n_1}e^{-\lambda_1x}e^{\lambda_2x}(\frac{d}{dx})^{n_2}e^{-\lambda_2x}...e^{-\lambda_sx}(\frac{d}{dx})^{n_s}e^{\lambda_sx}y=0$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Then you need to invert each operator from the left to the right. Let's exemplify this procedure with the simple case of a second-order ODE characterized by $p(D) = (D-\lambda)(D-\mu) = e^{\lambda x}De^{-\lambda x} e^{\mu x}De^{-\mu x}$. Note that the operator $D^{-1}$ is interpreted as integration, with $D^{-1}0 = c = const$ in particular, in such a way that the problem $p(D)y = 0$ is solved as follows :
$$
\begin{align}
   e^{\lambda x}De^{-\lambda x} e^{\mu x}De^{-\mu x}y(x) &= 0 \\
   De^{-\lambda x} e^{\mu x}De^{-\mu x}y(x) &= 0 \\
   e^{-\lambda x} e^{\mu x}De^{-\mu x}y(x) &= c_1 \\
   De^{-\mu x}y(x) &= c_1e^{(\lambda-\mu)x} \\
   e^{-\mu x}y(x) &= c_1 \int e^{(\lambda-\mu)x} \,\mathrm{d}x + c_2 = 
      \begin{cases}
      \frac{c_1}{\lambda-\mu}e^{(\lambda-\mu)x} + c_2 & \text{if } \lambda \neq \mu \\
      c_1x + c_2 & \text{if } \lambda = \mu
      \end{cases} \\
   y(x) &= 
      \begin{cases}
      C_1e^{\lambda x} + C_2e^{\mu x} & \text{if } \lambda \neq \mu \\
      (C_1x + C_2)e^{\lambda x} & \text{if } \lambda = \mu
      \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
where the constants of integration have been renamed at the last step. Now, you need to apply this procedure successively several times in your attempt, where all the roots can be assumed to be distinct, because you have introduced their multiplicities already, hence
$$
\begin{align}
   e^{\lambda_1x}D^{n_1}e^{-\lambda_1x} e^{\lambda_2x}D^{n_2}e^{-\lambda_2x} \cdots e^{\lambda_sx}D^{n_s}e^{-\lambda_sx} y(x) &= 0 \\
   e^{-\lambda_1x} e^{\lambda_2x}D^{n_2}e^{-\lambda_2x} \cdots e^{\lambda_sx}D^{n_s}e^{-\lambda_sx} y(x) &= p_1(x) \\
   e^{-\lambda_2x} \cdots e^{\lambda_sx}D^{n_s}e^{-\lambda_sx} y(x) &= D^{-n_2}p_1(x)e^{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)x} + p_2(x) \\
   &\ldots
\end{align}
$$
where $p_1(x) = D^{-n_1}0 = c_1 + c_2x + \ldots + c_{n_1}x^{n_1-1}$ is a polynomial expression and $D^{-n_2}p_1(x)e^{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)x}$ corresponds to $n_2$ successive integrations (by parts) of this same polynomial with an exponential factor. It is to be noted that a single integration of the product of an exponential with a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $m$ is given by (cf. Gradshteyn & Ryzhik § 2.323)
$$
\int P(x)e^{ax} \,\mathrm{d}x = a^{-1}e^{ax} \sum_{k=0}^m (-a)^{-k}P^{(k)}(x),
$$
where $P^{(k)}$ denotes the $k^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of $P$.
